# Search text in comments using advanced search

Tags: support, comments, search

Having in mind that you can use `title:"text to look up"` and `body:"text to look up"`, I tried using:

```
comment:"text to look up"
comments:"text to look up"
```

but they do not work. **How can I search text in comments?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stack Overflow does not provide any direct way to search text in comments. You can try the following two options:

1. Use *StackExchange Data Explorer* to search in the *Comments* database table. You may use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/124643/search-keyword-in-user-comments).
2. Use Google search and restrict the search using `site:stackoverflow.com`

You may view your own comments from your [profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3585386/luchonacho?tab=activity&sort=comments) and then use browser's search.

To search across all comments, use [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/532566). SDSE tutorial is available [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).
<sub>Acknowledgement to [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) for the above links.</sub>

Comment: I'm interested in point 1, but I cannot pass the UserID bit. Any help guide on how to use that site?

Comment: @luchonacho every user has an unique id. Click on any user profile and you'll see an id similar to [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QQwwv.png) on the search bar :)

Comment: @luchonacho see [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/532566) and you might go over the [SEDE Tutorial](http://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial)

Comment: Oh, I see. But that implies running a search on one user at a time. I was thinking on a more comprehensive, faster approach. I might try point 2 then.

Comment: @rene Great! That is exactly what I want! Please provide answer to mark as accepted.

Comment: Meh @luchonacho I think Aziz can add it if they want. If I wanted to write an answer I would have done so.

Comment: I just noticed that if you try this and switch to meta, it still links to for example (made-up URL) stackoverflow.com/questions/12345 result with the matching number, not to (made-up URL) meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12345 . Manually tweaking the URL to point at meta fixes it. A bug perhaps?